# Controller defined without component scanning or bean definition

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller in my codebase whose package is not component scanned. This controller is also not defined in a bean in any XML.

Somehow, the controller is working. I'm guessing this is because there is some way of defining a controller in Spring without component scanning or defining it in a bean. However, this controller implements a class called AbstractControllerImpl, and the Helper implementation class IS getting component scanned.

Does the fact that the Helper is getting component scanned mean the Controller gets scanned too? Or if not, how is it possible that this controller works?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/something")
public class SomeController extends AbstractControllerImpl<SomeControllerHelper> {  
    //Some request mappings here
}
```

The abstract controller class it extends:

```
public abstract class AbstractControllerImpl<H extends Helper>
    implements Controller<H>
{    
    private H helper;    

    private BaseValidator validator;

    public H getHelper()
    {
        return helper;
    }

    public void setHelper(H helper)
    {
        this.helper = helper;
    }   

    public void setValidator(BaseValidator validator)
    {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public BaseValidator getValidator()
    {
        return validator;
    }

    public Errors doValidation(Object obj)
    {
        Errors validationErrors = new BindException(this, "");
        if (validator != null)
        {
            validator.validate(obj, validationErrors);
        }
        return validationErrors;
    }   
}
```

The Controller interface:

```
public interface Controller<H extends Helper>
{
    H getHelper();
}
```

The helper definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


   <bean id="someHelper" class="com.controller.SomeHelperImpl" />   

</beans>
```

The helper impl class (which is getting component scanned):

```
@Component("SomeControllerHelper")
public class ASomeControllerHelperImpl implements SomeControllerHelper {
    //Some methods here
}
```

**Edit:** My web.xml. I removed a few of the servlet mappings and changed some of the names, but this is what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>SomeApp</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.Log4jLoaderServlet
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>crossContext</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- This listener will load other application context file in addition to springweb-servlet.xml -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- The context params that read by ContextLoaderListener  -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Spring security filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlets/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlets/app-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>       

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>        
    <location>/portal/error/notfound/</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/portal/error/internalsystem/</location>
</error-page>

<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/c.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/unstandard-1.0</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/unstandard.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

Here is app-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean> 

    <bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">

        <property name="basename" value="views"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>                                 
                    <value>/WEB-INF/views/something/views.xml</value>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/views/views.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="preparerFactoryClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringBeanPreparerFactory"/>
    </bean>     
</beans>
```

rest-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dw.spring3.rest.controller" />
    <!-- To enable @RequestMapping process on type level and method level -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

root-application-cnntext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.base.notcontroller" />

    <import resource="/something/common-context.xml" />          
</beans>
```

Comment: Let's see your web.xml. Do you have any other spring xml context files? Do you have any `@Configuration` classes?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added my web.xml with some servlet-mappings removed. If there's something specific you think I should look for that's not in it, let me know and I will look. There is not a single `@Configuration` annotation in my entire application.

Comment: Can you show us your class-path scanning configuration?

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch Do you know what kind of file/name of file that would be defined in? There are a lot of config/xml files on this application and I'm not sure what you mean by class-path scanning.

Comment: you have 3 different spring context files listed in your web.xml... can you show us those, also?

Comment: not to be a stickler, but what is the package in which your controller resides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the fact that the Helper is getting component scanned mean the
>   Controller gets scanned too? Or if not, how is it possible that this
>   controller works?

No, that is not possible.

It is not entirely clear what your context configuration looks like given that you've

> removed a few of the servlet mappings and changed some of the names

but your `@Controller` class must be loaded into the context somewhere, possibly in

```
rest-servlet.xml:
```

which has

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dw.spring3.rest.controller" />
```

which is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` named `` `rest ``.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlets/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

---

You can add a no-arg constructor to your `@Controller` class and put a breakpoint in, look at the stack trace and identify in which context it is being initialized.

---

Note that `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` has been deprecated in Spring 3.2. Consider using `<mvc:annotation-driven>` to configure your MVC environment.

Comment: Ok, I just took your suggestion and added the breakpoint. Here's what the stack trace looks like: http://i.imgur.com/mMoFBrK.png . Does this mean that it had to have been defined in XML since it contains XMLWebApplicationContext calls?

Comment: @user886596 Yes, that is your first hint. I believe you can select the `XMLWebApplicationContext` method which will bring you to where that method is blocked. You can check that object's properties for a `location` that will tell you which file it is.